# SSIS Multiple insert statements in OLE DB Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, oledb

When I try to put more than one insert Statement in a OLE DB Command like this:

```
    INSERT INTO [TABLE_A] ([NAME_A]) VALUES (@a)
    INSERT INTO [RELATION_TABLE]([ID_A],[ID_B])
    VALUES (
        (SELECT [ID_A] FROM [TABLE_A] WHERE [NAME_A] = @a),
        (SELECT [ID_B] FROM [TABLE_B] WHERE [NAME_B] = @b)
    )
```

I get this error:

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.".

The sub-select statements return only one record each. The variables have been declared and set.
Any suggestions how to solve this or where the error exactly is?

Comment: Seems like more than 1 value actually is returned. Do INSERT with SELECT instead.

Comment: If the record that out puts doesn't matter use max for ID_A and ID_B

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running this query:

```
SELECT a.ID_A, b.ID_B
FROM TABLE_A a JOIN
     TABLE_B b
     ON a.NAME_A = @a AND b.NAME_B = @b;
```

This is likely to return duplicates -- indicating that you are wrong about the data.  There are duplicates.  You should probably fix the data and create a unique index or constraint on `name` in each table to ensure data integrity.

If this returns what you want, then phrase the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO [RELATION_TABLE]([ID_A],[ID_B])
    SELECT a.ID_A, b.ID_B
    FROM TABLE_A a JOIN
         TABLE_B b
         ON a.NAME_A = @a AND b.NAME_B = @b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the select statements return only one value.

```
SELECT [ID_A] FROM [TABLE_A] WHERE [NAME_A] = @a
SELECT [ID_B] FROM [TABLE_B] WHERE [NAME_B] = @b
```